# Most Helpful and Responsive Q/A or Technical Site for SharePoint

Tags: discussion

I can tell that sharepoint.stackexchange.com is the best. But what else?
Could you please share your favourite sites for SharePoint questions and answers?

Thanks.

Comment: You may be interested in Microsoft's community list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/aa905695

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favorites are:

- [Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/sharepoint)
- [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/sharepoint)
- [Nothing But SharePoint](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/Pages/default.aspx)